# Linux - how to break an infinite loop that occurs in a startup script

Tags: linux, boot, infinite-loop

I've made a shell script and configured it so it'll run at startup.
It seems that it causes an infinite loop since it waits for something that hasn't brought up yet.

I'm aware of the fact that it's a complete noob and stupid mistake, but since it occurs even before I get the chance to login, I don't know how to break this loop or somehow remove this script so it won't happen.

Can someone please advise?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please research for *"booting into single-user mode"*. You will get a no-frills `root` shell (you *might* have to mount the volume the script is on manually).

Then you can remove (or better: rename) the offending script, and reboot to resume the "normal" mode of operation.